# Add and remove checkboxes to a list then be able to change the order of them?

Tags: jquery, list, dynamic, checkbox

I am after some jQuery that will allow me to do the following: -

On the left I have a pre populated list of car features, which i can select and then change the order of these - moving them around the list. I also need to have an option to remove any of these features from the list.

Then on the right i need an input box where you can type to add new features to the list on the left. So i add new features and it builds up on top of the list?

How can i do this? thanks

Comment: Hi Paul, can you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: hopefully this works: http://jsfiddle.net/czenR/ but need to be able to remove them from the list and also drag the order around in the list?